# Dragging a formula over a selected range

Tags: vba, excel

Looking for a way that could help me drag a formula over a range with an autofill sentence, depending on a previous selected range through an application.selection.

I am stuck in the autofill statement as you can see below.

Code:

```
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
   Set range2 = Application.Selection
   Set range2 = Application.InputBox("Source Ranges:", xTitleId, range2.Address, Type:=8)

    Set range3 = Application.Selection
    Set range3 = Application.InputBox("Source Ranges:", xTitleId, range2.Address, Type:=8)


     range2.AutoFill Destination:=range3 'It returns "run time error 1004 autofill method of range failed
```

Here is a background picture of what I want to do...

[image]

Comment: is your top left cell matching for source and destination when using autofill? It should I believe

Comment: Yes of course...

Comment: Over which range? You can't drag it in two directions at once.

Comment: Not sure what you are attempting here. You are setting `range3` to a range then setting it to a return value from `Application.Inputbox` which is a Boolean. Then you are attempting to set `AutoFill` to a Boolean value?

Comment: Just to correct myself, the return value from `Application.Inpubox` is not a Boolean, its and integer. But the question still stands

Comment: @Zac - type 8 is a range?

Comment: @Zac its a range

Comment: My bad.. didn't see the `type:=8` at the end

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but why you just don't copy formula to other cells?

Comment: @TomJohnRiddle all of this is created from dynamic tables, that's why I am using macros

Comment: you can't fill across and down in one go

Comment: @Robin_Hcp right, but why just not copy formulas using macros?

Comment: how? @TomJohnRiddle

Comment: `Destination` has to be a 1-row or 1-column Range, with the original cell at the Start or End of the range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you do this? Range 2 is single cell at present. Use FormulaR1C1 to keep relative references.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim range2 As Range
    Dim range3 As Range

    Set range2 = Application.Selection
    Set range2 = Application.InputBox("Source Ranges:", "Text", range2.Address, Type:=8)

    Set range3 = Application.Selection
    Set range3 = Application.InputBox("Source Ranges:", "Text", range2.Address, Type:=8)

    range3.Formula = range2.Formula

End Sub
```

Example with FormulaR1C1

[image: Example]

Comment: is range2 a single cell?

Comment: it's a variable range, in this case it would be equal B4:E7

Comment: And are there different formulas in B4:E7?

Comment: What I am trying to do is automatically drag down the formulas over a dynamic range, in this case the range is B4:E7 (but I do not want to focus on the range)

Comment: but are you trying to drag the formula for B4 over B4:E7?

Comment: it's the same formula, but with different cells integrating it

Comment: Can you include an example formula from B4 in the question (not as a picture) ?

Comment: 1+1 as a formula, my method works so something else is going on.

Comment: =IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(--(INDIRECT($A$2&"["&B$3&"]")=INDIRECT($A$2&"["&$A4&"]")),--(INDIRECT($A$2&"["&B$3&"]")<>0),--(INDIRECT($A$2&"["&$A4&"]")<>0))/COUNTIFS(INDIRECT($A$2&"["&B$3&"]"),"<>0",INDIRECT($A$2&"["&$A4&"]"),"<>0"),0)

Comment: Still works with using .Formula; just shift relative cells with   range3.FormulaR1C1 = range2.FormulaR1C1 Are you actually getting an error message?

Comment: the same message error as above mentioned, even with range3.FormulaR1C1 = range2.FormulaR1C1

Comment: it does not fill the formula over the cells

Comment: Do you have the b4 selected when running it? As in gif you can see it should fill.

Comment: got it.. Thanks a lot ! @QHarr

Answer (score 0):

If you have corner cells `TopLeftCell` and `BottomRightCell` as the Corners for your range-to-fill, then you can fill the rectangle like this:

```vb
With Range(TopLeftCell, BottomRightCell)
    If .Columns.Count > 1 Then .Rows(1).FillRight 'First fill horizontally
    If .Rows.Count > 1 Then .FillDown 'Then fill vertically
End With
```

If you have `FormulaCell` and `OtherCorner` as your corner-cell ranges then you need to extend with checks as to whether  you fill Right/Left or Up/Down: (i.e work out which diagonals and which direction to fill)

```vb
With Range(FormulaCell, OtherCorner)
    If .Columns.Count > 1 Then 'More than 1 column, fill horizontal
        If FormulaCell.Column < OtherCorner.Column Then
            Intersect(.Cells, FormulaCell.EntireRow).FillRight
        Else
            Intersect(.Cells, FormulaCell.EntireRow).FillLeft
        End If
    End If
    If .Rows.Count > 1 Then 'More than 1 row, fill vertical
        If FormulaCell.Row < OtherCorner.Row Then
            .FillDown
        Else
            .FillUp
        End If
    End If
End With
```